# Bash syntax for submission script

Tags: bash

I have a small bash script that has a following structure:

```
cd {PATH1}
bash {SCRIPT1} &
sleep 3600
cd {PATH2}
bash {SCRIPT2} &
sleep 3600
...
```

Each "record" consist of 3 lines:

- The first line brings me to a directory from which I will start a workflow. It has to stay that way i.e. I have to move to a directory first and then submit from there.
- The second line calls a bash scripts that set a big workflow in motion. Note that I move it to the background so that I can process the other "records"
- The third line is putting this script to sleep for 1h. This is necessary due to the nature of the workflows.

I would like it to be a master script that submits ~100 workflows.
Now, my problem is that I just noticed that if some of the workflows raise errors then the script does not submit the rest anymore...
How should I adjust it so that each workflow gets submitted regardless of the result of any single one?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to tell why it's stopping. Please include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce what you are saying. Here's what I wrote up based on what you described:

```
$ cat workflow.sh 
#!/bin/bash

set -x

cd /opt/
false &
sleep 1
cd $HOME
false &
sleep 1
```

Here, `false`, emulates a job submission that fails. And when I run it everything runs:

```
$ bash workflow.sh 
+ cd /opt/
+ sleep 1
+ false
+ cd /home/omajid
+ sleep 1
+ false
$ echo $?
0
```

Do you have a `set -e` or similar in your script? A `set -e` makes bash exit your script as soon as the first command fails.